# select from Mysql and put into variable VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a problem with the following piece of code:

```
dim nama as string    
cnn.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost; user id=root; password=; database=aplikasi_store_testing;"
        cmd.Connection = cnn
        cnn.Open()
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ID_Barang, Nama_Barang from data_barang WHERE ID_Barang= '" & txtIDBarangInput.Text & "';"
```

Afterwards, I would need to change the data from "Nama_Barang" to nama.
Could anyone help me with this? In advance, thank you very much for your precious help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you need to execute your command

```
dim nama as string    
cnn.ConnectionString = "............"
cmd.Connection = cnn
cnn.Open()
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ID_Barang, Nama_Barang from data_barang WHERE ID_Barang= @id"
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", txtIDBarangInput.Text )
Dim reader  = cmd.ExecuteReader()
while reader.Read()
   nama = reader(1).ToString()
End While
```

Of course this code assumes that you have already declared the connection and the command object.
Note also that I have removed your string concatenation and placed a parameter placeholder.
This is the right thing to do when you build strings to pass to the database engine.
Read about this subject ([Sql Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work))

By the way, selecting back the value of `ID_Barang` that you already know is useless.
Also, on this field, I have a doubt. In your question code you put the value between single quotes treating the value as a string. But the name `ID_Barang` suggest a numeric value. Are you sure that this field is a text?

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Nama_Barang from data_barang WHERE ID_Barang = '" & txtIDBarangInput.Text & "';"

Dim o As Object = cmd.ExecuteScalar()

If (Not o.Equals(DBNull.Value)) Then
    nama = DirectCast(o, string)
Else
    name = string.Empty
End If
```

You should use parameters rather than inserting the id value directly into the query string to avoid sql injection vulnerabilities etc.